# Closedness of the budget set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have this budget set, $B=\{x│x \in (\mathbb{R}^{+})^n, p \cdot x \le y\}$ where $p$ is the price vector and is assumed to be $ > 0$ and $y$ is our income which is $\ge 0$. How can we show that the set $B$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The essential fact is that the inner product function is continuous, and the inverse image of a closed set is closed.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a bit more on the continuity of the inner product function? So this function maps x into p⋅x, then how do you show that for every ε>0 there is a δ>0  such that f(Bδ(x)) is a subset of Bε(p⋅x)? where f is our inner product function. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleTseng When you look at it in terms of coordinate functions, it's basically a polynomial: sums and products of different coordinate projections, combined. Then all sorts of general facts (like sum and products are continuous etc.) combine to give continuity for the inner product. You don't show $\epsilon$-$\delta$ directly most of the time, if you can avoid it.